# Identifying all polygons connected by major river/stream

Tags: arcgis-pro, network, connectivity-analysis

I'm using ArcGIS Pro. I have a rivers (line) dataset, and a census tract (polygon) dataset. My goal seems relatively simple--polygons are considered "contiguous" if they are connected via a river body (like red lines in screenshot). How do I achieve this? Challenge seems to be identifying the line intersection with the 2 polygons ON BOTH sides of the line-- not just one.

[image]

Comment: Select your rivers then select those polygons that intersect the selected rivers?

Comment: Erase river by polygons, explode to single parts. Generate Near table between result and polygons using search radius close to zero. Calculate frequency for segment fid and join it to segments. Way more complicated if river is not a single line.